# Inserting variables into SQL query for node-mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

In the wiki for node-mysql, I noticed that variables (kind of) were inserted into the SQL query in 2 different ways, one is by inserting a variable in the middle of the query string, and the other way is by putting `?` in the query string and defining the values for these `?` in an array in the next argument. The values replacing `?` in the query are escaped.

What is the difference and when should I use one over the other? (If we want the table name to be a variable, should it be escaped?)

**Wiki Code**

```
client.query(
    'INSERT INTO '+TEST_TABLE+' '+
    'SET title = ?, text = ?, created = ?',
    ['super cool', 'this is a nice text', '2010-08-16 10:00:23']
);
```

**Wiki Link**: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

**Wiki extract**:

Sends a sql query to the server. '?' characters can be used as placeholders for an array of params that will be safely escaped before sending the final query.

This method returns a Query object which can be used to stream incoming row data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always favor option 2, since they are SQL injection proof. Option 1 will get your site hacked within 5 minutes, while hackers are going to have a hard time breaking option 2.

Even in performance option 2 may be a little bit faster.

**However**: Table names cannot be escaped with the `?` so don't go there. Just make sure that users can't enter the table name manually and you'll be safe from hackers.

-edit-

Why would you want to make table names variable anyway?

Comment: I want the tables to be variable depending on whether I'm running on local development environment or on the live server where the table names are different

Comment: In that case, make sure that no user can control the variables and you're good to go :-) For inserting values into queries, always use the `?`

Comment: Ok great. BTW, how can someone inject SQL if tables is made a variable?

Comment: I'm sure they'd find a way. They always do.